# Android textview rotates only visually

Tags: android, android-studio, frontend

I need to rotate textview. I use `android:rotation="-90"`. Visually it is:

```
x
x
x
```

But in fact it is:

```
x x x
```

[image: And that leads to constraint problems.]

Is there any way to rotate constraint box too?

TextView xml

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/recommendationTextView"
        android:layout_width="123dp"
        android:layout_height="19dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:textColor="#4d4d4d"
        android:letterSpacing="0.06"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="7sp"
        android:text="@string/recommendations"
        android:rotation="-90"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/itemEnd"
        android:layout_marginTop="74dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="74dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
```

Comment: Do you want the text to be vertically allignned?

Comment: Can you post your full xml?

Comment: I don't want to write in "letter for row" style. I literally want to rotate letters by 90 degrees. Here is my code: https://pastebin.com/kWhZuryG

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like there is no native solution to this problem. I've exported text with rotation as png from Zeplin. At least it works.